Copy font to Zebra printer from cmd
I am struggling with font copy to Zebra printer via CMD.
Everything seems pretty clear and easy, maybe I missing something but cannot get it done.
What I´ve tried:
Simple copy to shared Zebra printer

Seems like job done, but the LED on my Zebra printer keeps blinking (that should be the sign that the data is being copied to printer)
The blinking keeps going for more then 30 min, which is unreal I think and I can see also a stuck job at printer queue. (Yes I have tried restarting the printer,computer and every time this happens)

There are some other ways to get a font to printer I know but I want to solve is trough CMD, if possible.
Details:
Printer: Zebra GT800 connected via USB on port USB001
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you !

You can't just copy the font; it needs to be wrapped in a zpl command to get it properly installed.  Do you have the Zebra Utilities installed?  They are free and are the easiest way to download fonts to a printer.

Your question is unrelated to an issue with a command written in [[tag:cmd]]. It is not on topic for this site.

@MarkWarren I know Zebra Utilities, but in the production there are thousands of printers and its not a way to istall the ZU everywhere, can you help me to get the zpl command if it is possible ?

If you have node-js installed, you can use the following bit of code.
Save as file sendfont.js, then run as:
> node sendfont.js c:\path\to\font.ttf R:MYFONT.FON printer-addr

The code sends the font using ~DU, then queries the printer to ensure the font installed correctly.  You may want to add smarter error checking on that query.  It currently just displays the result of the ^HW command.
// sendfont.js
const fs = require('fs');
const net = require('net');

if (process.argv.length != 5) {
    console.log('Usage: node sendfont.js font-path zplname printer-addr');
    process.exit(1);
}

const path = process.argv[2];   // e.g. c:\\path\\to\\font.ttf
const zname = process.argv[3];  // e.g. R:MYFONT.FON
const addr = process.argv[4];   // hostname or ip address

let buf = fs.readFileSync(path);
let zpl = '~DU' + zname + ',' + buf.length + ',' +
          buf.toString('hex');

// Send the font, then query to verify
(async () => {
    await zsend(addr, zpl);
    console.log('' + (await zsend(addr, '^XA^HW' + zname + '^XZ', true)));
    process.exit(0);
})();

function zsend(addr, text, recv) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let timer = null;
        let result = null;
        const client = new net.Socket();

        client.setNoDelay();
        client.connect(9100, addr, () => {
            client.write(text, () => {
                if (recv) {
                    timer = setTimeout(resolve, 2500);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        client.on('data', (data) => {
            result = result ? Buffer.concat([result, data]) : data;
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            // Wait for more data
            timer = setTimeout(()=>{ resolve(result); }, 200);
        });
        client.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
}

I pulled that code together from existing code.  Hopefully it works.  Don't have a printer to test with where I am currently.
